Definition of integral of an almost everywhere non-negative, measurable function
Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measurable space and $(X, \overline{\mathcal{M}}, \overline{\mu})$ be its completion.
Let $f \colon X \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be an almost everywhere defined function.
We assume that $f$ is non-negative and measurable.
How to defined the integral $\displaystyle \int f \mathrm{d}\mu$?
By definition, there exists a $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable function $g \colon X \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f = g$ almost everywhere.
Let $N \in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$ such that $f = g$ on $X \setminus N$.
Do we set
$$\int f \mathrm{d}\mu = \int g1_{X \setminus N} \mathrm{d}\overline{\mu}$$
where $1_{X \setminus N}$ is the characteristic function of $X \setminus N$?
